# Send Keys to a text field using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I have to send the string to the textfield in the webpage . 
I tried to access it by xpath but the xpath keeps on changing everytime I open the webpage newly. So I decided to access it using class name or tag name. But I am getting an error that the keys can not be passed to the access field.

HTML of the textfiled in the webpage:

```
<div class = "SearchBox">
   <input aria-label = 'xyz' placeholder = 'abc'>
</div>
```

I tried with these lines of code but none of it is working:

```
    text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,'SearchBox')] and input[contains(@aria-label,'xyz')]')

    text =  driver.find_element_by_class_name('SearchBox')

    text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='SearchBox']/input")

    text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='SearchBox']/input[contains(@aria-label,'Combobox expanded. Use arrow keys to select available options or type to search.') and @dojoattachpoint='_searchInput']")
```

What am I doing wrong? Kindly help.

Error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    l.send_keys("abcdef")
  File "C:\Users\Pavan-Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\Pavan-Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Pavan-Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Pavan-Kumar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.146)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

HTML Code Pic:

[image: HTML Code]

Comment: dont see any error..please post more code or atleast the url which you are trying to scrape

Comment: @Sarthak Negi Actually it is IBM jazz server.You got to have a account to access the webpage.

Comment: paste the error log as xpath of Access_text looks wrong by the quotes

Comment: @thebadguy I have edited the question.Please have a look now.

Comment: @gopalakrishna Update the question with text based HTML

Answer (score 2):

The xpath that you jave written contains identifiers of both the div tag and the input tag. How will Selenium understand that you are trying to access the input field!!!!
If you are trying to use the div tag as an anchor to reach the input tag, your xpath should look something like this...
//div[@class='SearchBox']/input

Comment: I tried this .Its not working.I have edited the question please have a look now.

Comment: Is there another div tag with class 'SearchBox' somewhere higher up the DOM that has style -> display:none???

Answer (score 2):

The below xpath should help you as per the html structure image you shared.

```
//div[@class='SearchBox']/input[contains(@aria-label,'expanded') and @dojoattachpoint='_searchInput']
```

Comment: This should nail the OP

Comment: @KireetiAnnamaraj Thanks for the answer,  but it did not work.Error Log:raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

Comment: @Keerti Annamaraj I tried with this :  text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='SearchBox']/input[contains(@aria-label,'Combobox expanded. Use arrow keys to select available options or type to search.') and @dojoattachpoint='_searchInput']")

Comment: @gopalakrishna, 'Element not visible' exception is thrown when the element though is present in the DOM but not displayed. However, did it work after changing the xpath to: `//div[@class='SearchBox']/input[contains(@aria-label,'Combobox expanded. Use arrow keys to select available options or type to search.') and @dojoattachpoint='_searchInput']` as you mentioned? If not, try with this xpath `//div[contains(@style,'')]/div[@class='SearchBox']/input[contains(@aria-label,'expanded') and @dojoattachpoint='_searchInput']`. If still not visible, you need to debug why it is not displayed.